# how to code google chart in gwt using native javascript

Tags: gwt, google-visualization

I am trying to display google chart using gwt native javascript but i am not getting any output below is my code:

GwtChart.html

```
<!doctype html>
<!-- The DOCTYPE declaration above will set the     -->
<!-- browser's rendering engine into                -->
<!-- "Standards Mode". Replacing this declaration   -->
<!-- with a "Quirks Mode" doctype is not supported. -->

<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">

    <!--                                                               -->
    <!-- Consider inlining CSS to reduce the number of requested files -->
    <!--                                                               -->
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="GwtChart.css">

    <!--                                           -->
    <!-- Any title is fine                         -->
    <!--                                           -->
    <title>Web Application Starter Project</title>

    <!--                                           -->
    <!-- This script loads your compiled module.   -->
    <!-- If you add any GWT meta tags, they must   -->
    <!-- be added before this line.                -->
    <!--                                           -->

    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="gwtchart/gwtchart.nocache.js"></script>
  <script  type="text/javascript"  src="http://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>     


  </head>
  <body>
<div id="visualization" style="width: 600px; height: 400px;"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

GwtChart.java

```
public class GwtChart implements EntryPoint {

    //ChartServiceAsync chartService=GWT.create(ChartService.class); 

    public void onModuleLoad() {

        createChart() ;

    }

     private native void createChart() 
          /*-{

    $wnd.google.load('visualization', '1', {packages: ['corechart']});

      function drawVisualization() {
        // Create and populate the data table.

        var data = $wnd.google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
          ['Year', 'Austria', 'Bulgaria', 'Denmark', 'Greece'],
          ['2003',  1336060,    400361,    1001582,   997974],
          ['2004',  1538156,    366849,    1119450,   941795],
          ['2005',  1576579,    440514,    993360,    930593],
          ['2006',  1600652,    434552,    1004163,   897127],
          ['2007',  1968113,    393032,    979198,    1080887],
          ['2008',  1901067,    517206,    916965,    1056036]
        ]);


        new $wnd.google.visualization.BarChart($wnd.document.getElementById('visualization')).
            draw(data,
                 {title:"Yearly Coffee Consumption by Country",
                  width:600, height:400,
                  vAxis: {title: "Year"},
                  hAxis: {title: "Cups"}}
            );
      }


      $wnd.google.setOnLoadCallback(drawVisualization);
         }-*/;


        }
```

can any body help me coding google chart using native javascript in gwt.

Comment: why don't you use the `GWT wrapper` ? It could be that the visualization libary hasn't been loaded yet, when you call 'createChart` what does Chrome Dev Tools console say?

Answer (score 1):

What makes you want to do it native?

I usually use [wrapper from here](https://code.google.com/p/gwt-google-apis/wiki/VisualizationGettingStarted)

Is that not working for you?

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your reply.
I had tried with wrapper class and its working fine. 
But earlier I was trying with native js so i am wondering what is wrong in the native js that's why i posted this question.

Answer (score 1):

1) try this:

```
$wnd.google.load("visualization", "1.0", {packages : [ 'corechart' ], callback: drawVisualization});
```

instead of these 2 lines:

```
$wnd.google.load('visualization', '1', {packages: ['corechart']});


$wnd.google.setOnLoadCallback(drawVisualization);
```

or 
2) call google.load in your HTML page with

```
<script type="text/javascript"  src="http://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>     
<script type="text/javascript">
    google.load("visualization", "1", {'packages' : ["corechart"] });
</script>
```