# Google Visualization And Php Array

Tags: javascript, php, gwt, google-visualization

I'm trying to draw google visualization chart by passing php array. I dont find what my problem is, please provide suggestions, below is my code...

```
<html>
<head>
<?php 
    $test = array(  
            array('Date', 'Values'),  
                    array('June 25', 12.25),  
                    array('June 26', 8.00)
                );
    $test = json_encode($test); 
?>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
      google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["corechart"]});
      google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
      function drawChart() {
        var data = google.visualization.DataTable();
            data.addColumn('string', 'Date');
            data.addColumn('string', 'Values');
        data.addRows(<?php echo $test; ?>);

        var options = {
          title: 'Testing'
        };

        var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
        chart.draw(data, options);
      }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="chart_div" style="width: 900px; height: 500px;"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

And can this be implemented in gwt earth

Comment: First of all you have to set var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();  So you forgot the new keyword

Comment: Second of all the values column is defined as a string but in the array you are sending a number...so the second data.addColumn should be something like data.addColumn('number', 'Values'); If these work for you let me know so I can merge them in one answer that you can mark as correct.

Comment: @OviFaur Thanks for suggestion...but the problem still exits. It is problem with php array passing??? when i manually load data i.e. data.addRows([['June 25', 12.25],['June 26', 8.00]]); the charts loads...also with array passing there occurs no error, only map is not loaded where it should be.

Comment: With the suggestions Ovi Faur made, this looks like it should be working.  Can you update your question with the code as it appears to a browser (open in a browser and view source) so I can see what the PHP is outputting?

Comment: I figured what my silly mistake was..i was mistakely saving file in *.html...thanks @OviFaur for valuable suggestion, it was of great help.

Comment: Also can this code be implemented using native javascript method...if yes please provide me with some examples!!!

Comment: What do you mean by "native javascript method"?

Comment: Here is link for google chart in gwt using native javascript (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20738401/how-to-code-google-chart-in-gwt-using-native-javascript) ... but example is only for manually loading data and when i try using php array, it creates no chart.